# Converting String to Date throws parse exception

Tags: java, android, datetime, date-format, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert String to Date to compare from current Date and it throws parse Exception

```
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);  
        try {  
            java.util.Date cookiedate = format.parse("Tue Apr 29 11:40:55 GMT+04:00 2014");  

            Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

            String dateNow = format.format(currentDate.getTime());
              java.util.Date currDate =  format.parse(dateNow);

            if (currDate.getTime() > cookiedate.getTime()) {
                return true;
            }


        } catch (ParseException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
```

Comment: Don't you think that you need to change the SimpleDateFormat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you should parse the string date to `Date` object using `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy` format then convert that `Date` to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format as follows...

```
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");  

    try {  
        Date cookiedate = format.parse("Tue Apr 29 11:40:55 GMT+04:00 2014");  

        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

        format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

        cookiedate = format.parse(format.parse(cookiedate));

        String dateNow = format.format(currentDate.getTime());
        Date currDate =  format.parse(dateNow);

        if (currDate.getTime() > cookiedate.getTime()) {
            return true;
        }


    } catch (ParseException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `format`, `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` will match date string like `"2013-03-30 15:57:00"`, so you get a `ParseException`.

If you want to parse `"Tue Apr 29 11:40:55 GMT+04:00 2014"`, you should use `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"` Change your code to

```
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is pretty obvious that formatted date `"Tue Apr 29 11:40:55 GMT+04:00 2014"` does not match format `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`.

If you are using format `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` you should parse strings like `2014-03-30 10"59:23`.

If you want to parse string like `"Tue Apr 29 11:40:55 GMT+04:00 2014"` you should use format like `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy`. (I am not sure about `z`, probably it should be `Z`).